# iOS TableViews - Move cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am a beginner in xCode and I'm trying to make a simple app.

I'm using xCode 4.4.1 and want to make a `TableView` with many cells.
When I click on a cell, it should show a `ViewController` with a favorite button at the top.

When this button is pressed, it will move the cell to another `TableView`, used for favourites.

I've tried searching for an answer but did not find anything, so I'm looking for a complete tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it in terms of "moving a cell" - think of it in terms of moving or flagging the source data for the table.

Your first table will need a model from which to get its data - let's assume that's an `NSArray` containing objects that will be displayed in the table.

If you want a list of favourites, you'll need a way of keeping track of which elements in the array of data feeding your table has been flagged as a favourite. You could do this by copying the elements into another favourites array, or by setting a flag on the data object in response to the button press.

Then your favourites table will either load from the favourites array; or could filter the main array to retrieve only those elements that have been flagged.

Comment: oki thanks for your reply ::)
but the question is how do I do it :)
or is it better to spend the whole if one is so ignorant as me: D